# Why do I need to dereference iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Why do I need to dereference iterators? For example in the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string s("some string");

    for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); && !isspace(*it); ++it)
        *it = isupper(*it);
    cout<<s;
}
```

Why is it necessary to use `isupper(*it);` instead of just `isupper(it);`?

Comment: Note that the code you quoted makes no sense because you're assigning a boolean value to a character inside the loop.  You may want to use `toupper()` instead.

Comment: Yes. I realized that a few seconds after posting the question. Haha!

Comment: What you're referring to is called *dereferencing*, not referencing.

Comment: What's an upper case iterator?

Comment: @user2474562: fix the question instead of replying, as it will avoid some poor bastard a waste of time (you never know what gets copy pasted).

Answer (score 11):

Iterator is a generalized pointer. It *points* to something. If you have a function that needs that something(char or int, in this case), not the "pointer" itself, you need to dereference the iterator.

For example, the standard `advance` function takes an iterator as its argument. Therefore you pass the iterator without dereferencing it, as in

```
std::advance(it, n);
```

But if you have an iterator that points to an int and you want to increment that integer by 4, you need

```
(*it) += 4;
```

I suggest that you should read [a good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

By the way, your entire loop can be replaced by a single call to transform

```
 std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), toupper);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'm currently reading c++ primer 5th edition. It's going alright. Anything better you can recommend? I've seen the thread you posted, but I'm not experienced enough to pick out the good ones.

Comment: @Armen `toupper` is an overloaded function, your `transform` example is not guaranteed to work. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/strings.html#strings.string.simple

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was told that passing possibly negative values to `<cctype>` is formaly undefined behaviour and that one should always cast the argument to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @user2474562: C++Primer is the way to go, IMO

Comment: @jrok, it must be _representable_ as `unsigned char` (or equal `EOF`) so negative values are OK if they fit in an `unsigned char`

Answer (score 4):

You need to be able to perform operations on the iterator itself e.g. your code does `it != s.end()` and `++it`

And sometimes you need to be able to perform operations on the object the iterator points to, e.g. `isupper(*it)`

There has to be *some* operation to indicate you want to refer to the thing it refers to not the iterator itself, otherwise if you test  `if (it == another_it)` how would the compiler know if you were trying to compare the iterators or the things they point to?  The same applies to the `++it` operation, which wants to modify the iterator, not the thing it points to.

Iterators could have a `get()` member to return the thing they refer to, so you'd do `isupper(it.get())` but instead they support the dereference operator, which is less typing and is consistent with pointers and allows pointers to be used in any code that expects iterators.

Answer (score 2):

In order to distinguish operations on pointer-to-T and operations on the subject T it is necessary to have a dereferencing operator.

For example:

```
int* x = ...;

x++;
```

Do you mean you want to increment the pointer so it is pointing to the next int in memory?  Or do you want to increment the int pointed to by x?

Without the deferenencing operator this would be ambiguous.

Iterators are simply a generalization of the pointer interface.

Contrast with references:

```
int& x = ...;

x++;
```

References have the alternative semantic, and do not require dereferencing.  An operation on reference-to-T applies to the subject T.  The downside is that you can't modify the reference itself.